# I keep getting this error ' Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler": '

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I'm running Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 4.0.0, and I'm just starting to learn how to use Ruby on Rails. Whenever I type the command to run the server:

```
    $ rails s
```

I get this error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
    In Gemfile:
     rails (= 4.0.0) depends on
      bundler (< 2.0, >= 1.3.0)

   Current Bundler version:
     bundler (1.0.15)
```

So I updated it and then checked the version of the bundler using this command:

```
    $ gem list bundler
```

And this is the result I get:

```
    *** LOCAL GEMS ***

    bundler (1.3.5, 1.3.0)
```

Although it says this, I still continue to get the error as mentioned above. Anyone know how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to prefix it with `bundle exec`:

```
bundle exec rails server
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check bundler's version using

```
bundle -v
```

Prefixing your rails / rake command using `bundle exec` before will ensure ruby will use the gems required by your application.

```
bundle exec rails s
```